# ASP.NET 4.5 Ajax works fine on local but Ajax client-side framework failed to load when hosted in a web server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, iis, web-config

I am using ScriptManager and UpdatePanel in my website and every thing works in local machines when it was debugged from visual studio 2012 but when its hosted in web server it gives couple of erros:

Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
Uncaught Reference Error: Sys is not defined

and also it doesn't load scriptresources.axd file as it was saying 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Well, this is a quite generic and infamous Error ^^. Do you have URL rewriting enabled ?  

Also, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522040/375304)

Comment: Do not hesitate to post the answer to your question, this will help other people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my web.config file to the one as below

```
<modules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v13.1, Version=13.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```