# ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load error but ONLY in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>
```

`Sys` is undefined and the error is being thrown on an ASPX page but *only* in IE10.  Opera, Chrome, FF, and Safari all work fine!  I've dropped IE security to the "Low" position in case it was a permissions issue of some kind, but no joy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638436/asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load)

Comment: This only happens in IE.  Other browsers are working fine, so I surmise from that fact that it is not an IIS issue. The server seems to be working fine.